# How to disable some part to be displayed as TVOut in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, ios5, video-capture, screen-capture, mirroring

As we all know in iOS 5 we don't require to add separate lines of code of TVOut feature. They have integrated that functionality as an in-built feature.

What my question is: What if in my application there are some my custom views available, which i don't want to showcase as TVOut presentation. It should be display on device only, not on projection board.

I have checked the TVOut code which we use for iOS version <5.0, but there they are capturing window image and passing it. How to prohibit to pass screaming for some custom small views.

Any suggestions/solutions are most welcome.

Check out this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?gl=US&v=GysMfb4_79A

How to achieve such thing?

**Edit** :
I have used ExternalDisplay code given by Apple. But I am facing one issue in that.

- That code works for single view controller, where we add all our views to new window.
- What if my application contains so many view controllers, and in some of the view controllers I have textViews for the user.
- How to avoid to display those text views over the external window as TVOut, there should be display the view without that textView.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 3):

From the [ExternalDisplay](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ExternalDisplay/Listings/Classes_ExternalDisplayViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010724-Classes_ExternalDisplayViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6) sample code in the iOS Developer Library:

> To display content on an external display, do the following:
>
> 1. Use the screens class method of the UIScreen class to determine if an external display is available.
> 2. If an external screen is available, get the screen object and look at the values in its availableModes  property. This property contains
>      the configurations supported by the screen.
> 3. Select the UIScreenMode object corresponding to the desired resolution and assign it to the currentMode  property of the screen
>      object.
> 4. Create a new window object (UIWindow) to display your content.
> 5. Assign the screen object to the screen property of your new window.
> 6. Configure the window (by adding views or setting up your OpenGL ES rendering context).
> 7. Show the window.

Looking at the sample code you would have two `UIWindow` objects, each displays the views that would would like to show on that given display. So you could have a `UIViewController` with a flag `isExternalScreen`, and when true it would not show the certain views.

Comment: Hi Michael, Its great. But what my requirement is, there will be one image in say ViewController1, so its there on window. But while attaching any external TVOut resource, that image should not be displayed over presentation board, but it should be visible on device. Other part of the view controller will be as it is same as on device. I checked the code it creates completely new uiwindow where as i want to use the same window with all the other view parts.

Comment: Also I couldn't be able to get how this can be used in entire life cycle as generic code. As in this example they are dealing with specific view controller only. Where as I am dealing with UIWindow mainWindow itself. If you check https://github.com/robterrell/TVOutManager/blob/master/TVOutManager.m. Here we are capturing entire image of the window. As of now i am using this. But drawback is - this is compatible for <iOS 5. As iOS 5 does not required any specific code for TVOut feature.

Comment: I was able to run `TVOutManager` on iPad 5.1 Simulator without issue. To maintain genericness you could modify `TVOutManager` to send a message to the `UIWindow` upon the call of `-[startTVOut:]:` such as `- (NSArray)rectsToHide` where it returns an `NSArray` of `CGRect`s. (You can encapsulate a `CGRect` into an array by using: `[NSValue valueWithCGRect:<#(CGRect)#>]`) In the call of `- [updateTVOut:]:` the `CGRect`s from `- [rectsToHide]:` would be used draw rects on the `CGImageRef` generated by `UIGetScreenImage` with the background color matching the view, thus effectively hiding views.

Comment: When I tried in iOS 5 with the mentioned TVOutManager code, i was not able to get call for any of those functions. Please can you add some code here, that would be really helpful to me.

Comment: Michael: Can you please help on this?